# Confused with eigenvectors and bases for eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say I have found the $λ$ from the characteristic polynomial. Then I substitute it back into $(λI - A)$ and solve for it.

Suppose these are the answers that I got: $x=2r, y=r$ and $z=r$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

A basis would be $r(2,1,1)$, so $(2,1,1)$ is a basis for the eigenspace associated with $λ = 1$.

What is the eigenvector? Is it $(2r,r,r)$ or is it the same as the basis?

I am confused because my question asked me to solve $A^9x$ so I'm sure the way to solve it is using $A^9x=λ^9x$

So what should I put into $x$? $(2r,r,r)$ or $(2,1,1)$?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the eigenspace is a one-dimensional vector space 
$$ V_{\lambda} = \mathrm{span} (2,1,1) = \{ (2r, r, r) \, | \, r \in \mathbb{R} \}. $$
Any **non-zero** vector $v \in V_{\lambda}$ (for example, $(4,2,2)$) will be an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ (as it satisfies by definition $Av = \lambda v$). In addition, since $V_{\lambda}$ is one dimensional, any non-zero vector in $V_{\lambda}$ (any eigenvector) will also serve as a basis for $V_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Does that mean (2,1,1) , (4,2,2) , (6,3,3), etc are all eigenvectors assosciated with λ = 1? Basically anything in the form of (2r,r,r)

Comment: Yep. Note that sometime people say and write things like "the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ has two eigenvectors" and they usually mean "the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors" because usually there are infinitely many eigenvectors (they form a subspace) but to describe the eigenspace it is enough to provide a basis.